# Visual Studio Community 2015 offline download size

Tags: download, visual-studio

I am using /layout switch for Visual Studio 2015 community edition setup.
My download size is currently 12.8 GB.
I want to know what is the actual size of offline download.
Can anybody tell me the size?

Answer (score 1):

The ISO of the community edition appears to be 5.8GB. I don't know how compressed this is though or if there are additional packages you require.

[image: Screenshot of the Visual Studio installer]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the offline download includes all components like Java, NodeJS, Android SDK, Git etc.